# skinClass working in mxml, but not in external css

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have a simple button in a mxml file, if I set the skinClass property in the tag itself it works, however, if I set the skinClass property in an external css file, it doesn't apply to the button.

Works:

view.mxml

```
<s:Button id="btnRefresh" skinClass="skins.RefreshButtonSkin"/>
```

Doesn't work:

view.mxml

```
<s:Button id="btnRefresh"/>
```

style.css

```
#btnRefresh
{
    skinClass: ClassReference("skins.RefreshButtonSkin");
    fontSize: 12px;
}
```

Someone knows how I can get this css working?

Note: I can apply other styles to the button using the css, eg fontSize works

Edit: Additional info

The button is nested in the actionContent part of my view

view.mxml

```
<s:actionContent>
    <s:Button id="btnRefresh"/>
</s:actionContent>
```

The css file is declared in my main mxml file

main.mxml

```
<fx:Style source="style.css"/>
```

I'm compiling for flex 4.5.1, it's a mobile application

Comment: I can't see anything wrong in there (unless you'd be compiling for Flex 3). Do you have any additional information?

Comment: The skin is in a separate referencing library flex project.
I put the skin in the project itself, but still no succes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that this is a bug in the `ActionBar` component. I've tried id selector (`#btnRefresh`), class selector (`.btnRefreshStyle`), component selector (`s|Button`) and @Thembie's suggestion.

I've tried using `skinClass` and `skin-class`.

None of these work when the button resides in the `actionContent` property of the `View` component. But it all works fine when you move the button to the `View` component.

So I'm afraid you're stuck with hard-coding that skinclass. You might consider filing a bug report.

Comment: Seems you are right.
It doesn't even skin when I declare it as a style in css and use it in the styleName prop of the button
Tnx for your effort

Comment: hm, the problem seems to be with the style manager not being set properly on the button within actionContent.  Definitely a bug.

Answer (score 0):

s|Button#btnRefresh
{
    skinClass: ClassReference("skins.RefreshButtonSkin");

}

Comment: That isn't working, as I said I can apply other styles to the button using the css, so my selector seems to be OK

Answer (score 0):

defaults.css in the mobile theme has style rules for `ActionBar` with a higher CSS "specificity" level than the ID selector you're using.

Short answer: Use `#actionGroup #btnRefresh` as your selector.

Long answer: `ActionBar` has the following selectors for rules to support the "defaultButtonAppearance" style in the mobile theme:

```
ActionBar Group#navigationGroup Button
ActionBar Group#actionGroup Button
ActionBar.beveled Group#navigationGroup Button
ActionBar.beveled Group#actionGroup Button
```

These are in place to make it easy to swap out the flat-look buttons with the iOS-styled "beveled" buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Jason was right, the default.css in mobile theme override your s|Button#btnRefresh style.
In order for your skin to work, just make your style stronger like:

s|ActionBar s|Group#navigationGroup s|Button#btnRefresh{...}